# Меняется трактовка ASCII из-за склеивания символов

Tags: java, строки, char, int, приведение-типов

Если написать так, то выводится `257`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print((char) 126 + (char) 94 + (char) 37);
    }
}
```

А если так, то `~^%`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print((char) 126);
        System.out.print((char) 94);
        System.out.print((char) 37);
    }
}
```

Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

См. приведение типов в Java: [*5.1. Kinds of Conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1)

Этот код в неявном виде приводит символы `char` к типу `String`:

```java
System.out.print("" + (char) 126 + (char) 94 + (char) 37); // ~^%
```

А этот код приводит к типу `double`:

```java
System.out.print(.8 + (char) 126 + (char) 94 + (char) 37); // 257.8
```

---

<sup>См. дополнительно: [Why do I get a number when I add chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429041/16649492)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

В соответствии со [спецификацией Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) при суммировании двух примитивных `char` вы будете получать `int`.

Соответственно, в первом случае будет использован метод `print(int)`, а во втором случае — `print(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в первом случае выводится сумма трёх чисел, а во втором три отдельных символа.